# HTMLAgilityPack parse table within another table cell

Tags: c#, arraylist, html-agility-pack

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>header1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th></tr>
    <tr><td>value01</td><td>value02</td><td>value03</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value11</td><td>value12</td><td>value13</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <table>
                <tr><td>subvalue01</td><td>subvalue02</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using this code to save the main table cell values into separate `ArrayList` and subtable cell values in another `ArrayList`. But my `ArrayList` for subtable cell values is saving the entire values including table and subtable:

```
foreach (HtmlNode table in hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
{
    ///This is the table.
    foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr").Skip(1))
    {
        ///This is the row.
        foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td")) 
            ///can also use "th|td", but right now we ONLY need td
        {
            //This is the cell.
            if (cell.InnerHtml.Contains("<table>"))
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode subtable in cell.SelectNodes("//table"))
                {
                    foreach (HtmlNode subrow in subtable.SelectNodes("tr").Skip(1))
                    {
                        foreach (HtmlNode subcell in subrow.SelectNodes("th|td"))
                        {
                            arrSubList.Add(subcell.InnerText);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                arrList.Add(cell.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your first line

```
foreach (HtmlNode table in hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
```

will select ALL tables - at any level (including the nested tables).

Per: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

> //   Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the
>   selection no matter where they are

So, change your first line to

```
foreach (HtmlNode table in hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/table"))
```

And see how that goes.

Comment: Well I changed this line actually `foreach (HtmlNode subtable in cell.SelectNodes("//table"))` as you said and it worked.

Comment: Yes, that would work around the problem - but only by coincidence.  You should really investigate the result of `hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")`.  I can almost guarantee it isn't selecting what you think or want.

Comment: I changed that one to `HtmlNode table in hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/table")`

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect this.  Glad you got it sorted.